# Need some guidance on Ember component functionality

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently leveraging ember-cli-geolocate along with ember-google-maps to provide users with the closest point of interest to their current location. I've got the code working in a component but have now realized that I'm not able to sort.

Code below:

//routes/vineyard/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import $ from 'jquery';

const { Route, set } = Ember;

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('vineyard');
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    set(controller, 'vineyards', model);
  },
  activate() {
    this.controllerFor('vineyard/index').send('distanceFrom');
  }
});
```

//controllers/vineyard/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  userLocation: null,
  endLocation: null,
  milesAway: null,
  locationIsLoading: true,
  failState: false,
  googleMapsApi: service(),
  geolocation: service(),
  panelActions: Ember.inject.service(),
  userLocationChanged: function () {
    this.get('userLocation');
    this.toggleProperty('locationIsLoading');
  }.observes('userLocation'),
  actions: {
    distanceFrom: function() {
      this.get('geolocation').trackLocation().then((geoObject) => {
        let currentLocation = this.get('geolocation').get('currentLocation');
        this.set('userLocation', currentLocation);
      }, (reason) => {
        // this.toggleProperty('failState');
        // $('.error').css('height', '220px');
        // $('.error > p').css('height', 'auto');
        console.log('Geolocation failed because ' + reason);
      });
    },
    stopError: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('failState');
      $('.error').css('height', '0');
      $('.location-loader').animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000);
    }
  },
});
```

components/miles-away.js

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Component.extend({
  googleMapsApi: service(),
  geolocation: service(),
  userLocation: null,
  endLocation: null,
  milesAway: null,
  distanceLoading: true,
  errorState: false,
  fadeClass: '',
  didInsertElement() {
    this.set('self', this);
    var address = this.get('address');
    var location = this.get('location');
    var distanceLoading = this.get('distanceLoading');
    var userLocationLat = location[0];
    var userLocationLon = location[1];
    let userLocation = '' + userLocationLat + ',' + userLocationLon
    this.set('userLocation', userLocation);
    this.set('endLocation', address);
    this.send('getDistance');
  },
  actions: {
    getDistance: function() {
      // let milesAway = this.get('milesAway');
      let userLocation = this.get('userLocation');
      let endLocation = this.get('endLocation');
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.get('googleMapsApi.google').then((google) => {
        var self = this;
        let distanceMatrixService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        function calculateDistance() {
          distanceMatrixService.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [userLocation],
            destinations: [endLocation],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
          }, callback);
        }
        function callback(response, status) {
          if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            self.toggleProperty('errorState');
          } else {
            // var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
            // var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
            if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
              self.toggleProperty('errorState');
            } else {
              var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
              // var distance_value = distance.value;
              var distance_text = distance.text;
              // const miles = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
              self.toggleProperty('distanceLoading');
              self.set('milesAway', distance_text);
              later((function() {
                $('.miles-away').addClass('fade-in');
              }), 45);
            }
          }
        }
        calculateDistance();
      });
    },
  }

});
```

components/miles-away.hbs

```
{{#unless distanceLoading}}
  <div class="miles-away-container">
    <p class="miles-away">{{milesAway}}</p>
  </div>
{{/unless}}
{{yield}}
```

and finally, the template in which this is rendered..(just providing a snippet)

templates/vineyard/index.hbs

```
   <div class="distance">
          {{#if failState}}
            {{svg-jar 'fail'}}
          {{/if}}
          {{#if locationIsLoading}}
            {{location-loader}}
            {{else}}
            {{miles-away location=userLocation address=vineyard.location}}
          {{/if}}
        </div>
```

I'm open to implementing this in a completely different way, I know it's not even close to proper or perfect.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to sort?" What are you trying to sort? What kind of errors do you get? The place to do sorting is whatever js file that goes with the hbs containing an `{{#each}}` helper (or on the controller, if the each is on a route)

Comment: I'm trying to sort by nearest location. I'm unsure with how to sort with the way it's setup now, and seems like I wouldn't be able to anyways, because location isn't fetched till the list/table is loaded onto the template.

Comment: *this distance to the location isn't fetched

Comment: I think what you probably want to do is, at whatever point you have all your data as collections (the user and all the vinyards), define a computed property that returns the sorted array of vinyard records. Use that in an each helper. You can write a custom sort that takes the geo data into account https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/sort